# Reference for Cochran-Orr-Teichner's filtrations on knot concordance

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

I would be interested in recommendations for easily accessible/somehow simply readable texts to Cochran-Orr-Teichner's filtrations on knot concordance:

> Tim D. Cochran, Kent E. Orr, and Peter Teichner. "Knot concordance, Whitney towers and L2-signatures." Annals of Mathematics (2003): 433-519.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are summarys of parts of Cochran, Teichner and Orr's paper in:

- [These lecture notes](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/surgery/sliceknots2.pdf) of Peter Teichner, typed up by Julia Collins and Mark Powell;
- [Mark Powell's 2011 Edinburgh PhD thesis;](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/powellthesis.pdf)
- [Julia Collins' 2012 Edinburgh PhD thesis.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0669)

You'll find all of these references (and I'm sure more besides) at [Andrew Ranicki's webpage.](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/surgery/notes.htm)

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a geometric topologist, but as I was in Edinburgh around the time I ended up as one of the examiners of Julia Collins' thesis.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the monograph of J. C. Cha which discusses the rational version of filtrations of knot concordance groups comparing with the original paper.

> Cha, Jae Choon. The structure of the rational concordance group of knots. Vol. 182. American Mathematical Soc., 2007.

2. The following article includes a very nice application of Cochran-Orr-Teichner's work. Here, J. Collins reproved the classical theorem of Casson and Gordon about the sliceness of twist knots.

> Collins, Julia. "The $L^2$ signature of torus knots." arXiv preprint arXiv:1001.1329 (2010).